# Flow control pub/sub on global basis in client library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In the client library for Cloud Pub/Sub, we can specify flow control settings in order to ensure the subscriber is not being overwhelmed by messages. This works fine if you only have one subscription.

However, my server has many subscriptions, which are used to integrate with other services. Is there a way to enforce a global flow control of sorts in the client library, which would make it possible to evenly balance the flow of messages among the subscription instances?

I tried looking at the docs, and did some searching, but came up empty handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research, it seems that the only viable option to control the throughput more fine grained among multiple subscriptions, will be to use the lower-level api to perform synchronous pulls.